# How do I install the kurti devi 10 font for CKEditor?

Tags: theming

I want to use the kurti devi 10 font in my new project. How do I install it for CKEditor?

Comment: This is not much a Drupal question: You install a font in the same way you install it on any computer. Drupal doesn't handle fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [@font-your-face](http://drupal.org/project/fontyourface) module. It lets you to add fonts with UI, and it even have some kind of wysiwyg integration.